# show table row if id is in an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table

I have the following problem, that I don't know how to solve this.

I have a dropdown menu and a table and if one item of the dropdown is selected the table should only show the elements which are in this group.

the data came from an external service and will be refreshed every minute by calling `vehicleShowHide();` and `refreshTable();` (get the table data and creates the table).

I create an array with the ids and now I want to compare the ids in the array with the ids in table to show only the result and hide the others.

dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" onchange="showVehicleGroup(value)">
    <option value="" selected="">Alle Gorups</option>
    <option value="1-44060-041414BE3">Alle Vehicle (101)</option>
    <option value="1-44060-5211861A0">Group1 (42)</option>
    <option value="1-44060-477E11472">Group2 (3)</option>
    <option value="1-44060-4774E43D7">Group4 (23)</option>
    <option value="1-44060-288B143F2">Group5 (3)</option>
    <option value="1-44060-730090EA1">Group6 (6)</option>
</select>
```

the table (simpified):

```
<table id="vehicleTable" class="table table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
</thead>
  <tbody id="vehicleTableBody">
      <tr id="102">
          <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="103">
          <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="104">
          <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="105">
          <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="106">
          <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
function showVehicleGroup(value) {

if (groupFilterArray.length === 0) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    groupFilterArray = [];
}

$(vehicleObjectsArray).each(function(key, element) {

    if (element.objectgroupuid === value) {

        groupFilterObject = element.objectno

        groupFilterArray.push(groupFilterObject);

    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});

vehicleShowHide();
}

function vehicleShowHide() {

groupFilterArray = [ "103", "105", "106" ];

$('#vehicleTable').each(function() {

 // here I do not know how to compare the groupFilterArray with the table rows by id
    if () {
        $('#vehicleTable tbody tr#id').show();
    } else {
        $('#vehicleTable tbody tr').hide();
    }

});
```

external json (extraction):

```
[
 {
  "objectgroupname": "Group1",
  "objectno": "102",
  "objectname": "xxxxx",
  "objectuid": "1-44060-53078611D",
  "objectgroupuid": "1-44060-041414BE3"
 },
 {
  "objectgroupname": "Group2",
  "objectno": "103",
  "objectname": "xxxxx",
  "objectuid": "1-44060-3236707EF",
  "objectgroupuid": "1-44060-477E11472"
 }
]
```

Comment: what is the relation between the option of select box and table ?

Comment: @DsRaj The relation I see is, he is calling the method showVehicleGroup() on change of select box and from showVehicleGroup(), calling the method vehicleShowHide().

Comment: if you want to do this filter server side you can use the same function that refresh the table each minute passing the ID to that function. If the ID is passed show only the matching results. If the ID is not then show all the results

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vc_dinesh/f24zgseb/ have a look on this jsfiddle I think you need something Like this

Comment: thanks for your input. but in my case the table ids can be in one or more groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `indexOf` method and looping also to be changed.

ie;

```
 var groupFilterArray = [ "103", "105", "104" ];
 $('#vehicleTable #vehicleTableBody tr').each(function() {

    var rowId = $(this).attr("id");
        if (groupFilterArray.indexOf(rowId) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Try this code and let us know whether it works.  Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnelsonin/54L5bkx7/)
And Here is a code snippet which you can execute and see the result.

```js
 var groupFilterArray = [ "103", "105", "106" ];
 $('#vehicleTable #vehicleTableBody tr').each(function() {
    
    var rowId = $(this).attr("id");
        if (groupFilterArray.indexOf(rowId) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vehicleTable" class="table table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
</thead>
  <tbody id="vehicleTableBody">
      <tr id="102">
          <td>Text 102</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="103">
          <td>Text 103</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="104">
          <td>Text 104</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="105">
          <td>Text 105</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="106">
          <td>Text 106</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot and it works fine. now I understand the indexOf a little bit better.

Comment: @wuk986 my pleasure